# Converting Int32 to binary in c++

Tags: c++-cli, string-parsing

I'm asking for help here after searching all around the web

I'm working on a school project, in Windows Forms, using managed C++.
My problem is that I've got an Int32 value and I need to convert it to a binary value using System::Convert but I don't know how to use it properly.

I've tried doing this :

```
convertit = Int32::Parse(str);
static unsigned char ToByte(convertit);
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: @Rameleu it's really not clear what language you're targeting. Native C++ doesn't provide an Int32 class and my best guess would be that you're targeting managed C++. If that's the case, consider having a look at the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: I suspect that you actually want to convert to a string containing the binary representation of the number, i.e. its representation in base 2. Read through the documentation for `System::Convert` until you find a `ToString` that fits.

Comment: I've been searching for hours on the documentation, and I've accomplished nothing. Actually I've parsed a string (str) to an Int32, and now I want to convert this Int32 into a binary number.

Comment: @Rameleu It's still unclear what you're aiming for, especially because you're mentioning System::Convert but then talk about "binary number", because Int32 somehow already is a binary representation. Can you show an example of a complete conversion without code but just values, and then some of the examples you already tried? Anyway, maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter.GetBytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well my project is I need to make a binary to decimal calculator (and decimal to binary calculator)
I've made the binary to decimal part :
if(this->radioButtonBin->Checked==true)
    {
    int nb = System::Convert::ToInt32(str, 2);
    this->textBoxClosed->Text=nb.ToString();
    }

And now I need to make the other part, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. All I needed to do was

```
         // Binary button checked
         if(this->radioButtonBin->Checked==true)
         { 
         int nb = System::Convert::ToInt32(str, 2);
         this->textBoxClosed->Text=nb.ToString();
         }

         // Decimal button checked
         else
         {
         int nb = Convert::ToInt32(str, 10);
         String^ nb1 = System::Convert::ToString(nb, 2);
         this->textBoxClosed->Text=nb1;
         }
```

Comment: consider accepting a solution - also your own! You might have a look [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 0):

System::Convert can be used for both conversions since it supports base 2:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/swz6z5ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
   int i = System::Convert::ToInt32("101", 2);
   Debug::Assert(i == 5);
   // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
   System::String^ s2 = System::Convert::ToString(i, 10);
   Debug::Assert(s2 == "5");
   return 0;
}
```

Please note that microsoft doesn't mention the word "radix" in their documentation but it seems handy to know for further searches, see [Positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) - stackoverflow offers a lot when searching for "radix conversion" fe.

Generally, i'd recommend to always search for an example in another .net language if no cli example can be found.